# What is the use of multiple Jenkins plugin directory?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, cicd

I was trying to create a Jenkins master slave system using Helm Charts. [ https://github.com/jenkinsci/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/jenkins/README.md ].

After deploying I can see the plugins are stored in two locations in the pod/ docker container.

```
1. /var/jenkins_home/plugins

2. /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins
```

What's the relation between these two? JENKINS_HOME is configured as `/var/jenkins_home/`. If I need to backup the plugins which directory should I backup ?

For a plugin named `ace-editor`, I can see these many files in respective folders.

`/usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins` contains (1 file) -> ace-editor.jpi

`/var/jenkins_home/plugins` contains (4 file) -> ace-editor.jpi, ace-editor.jpi, ace-editor.jpi.pinned, ace-editor.jpi.version_from_image

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory to back up is always `/var/jenkins_home`. It is meant to be a persistent volume with all the data. `/var/jenkins_home/plugins` contains the downloaded `.jpi` plugin files and directories where each plugin has been unpacked.

The directory `/usr/share/jenkins/ref` is a "reference" directory on the container image. This means `/usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins` is used as a starting point to install a base set of plugins into `/var/jenkins_home/plugins` the first time you run Jenkins.

The log file containing info about installed reference files is `/var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log`.

The files with suffix `.pinned` or `.version_from_image` are used to control subsequent behaviour for example when plugins have been updated in `jenkins_home` from the UI and/or to the reference directory in a newer container image. Some users might want to use the bundled plugins in the image only for initial startup, others as the definitive source of all updates. See also environmental variables described in the [documentation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker#upgrading-plugins).

If you want to examine the inner workings you can find shell script `jenkins.sh` and functions source `jenkins-support` in the [repository root](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker) or in `/usr/local/bin` on the image.